# How to retrieve configuration values immediately after they're saved

Tags: magento, configuration, controller

I'm using a system.xml file to add a new section to to my Magento installation in `app/code/local/NameSpace/Module/etc/system.xml`. I've read that you can create an `IndexController` and override `postAction()` however of all the examples I've seen a custom layout is used rather than system.xml, is there a reason for this or can controllers be made to work for both of them?

If they can't is there any other way to have a file run after the user clicks 'Save Config' so I can immediately start using the values with `Mage::getStoreConfig()`?

Comment: The question you are asking is confusing multiple terms. Controllers are not connected to `system.xml`, outside of the fact that a controller renders the Sys Config view and a controller handles the post from it. What are you trying to do with the posted value?

Comment: @benmarks I'm trying to POST it off to another webpage in order to be used in an app for verification i.e. using curl.

Comment: Either use JS to do this or you can capture the post in an observer.